# Firefox print colspan borders on second page

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

I have a long table that can be printed only on 2 pages. The table also has colspans in the thead section. When printing the table, borders are missing from cells where there was a colspan above.

It's probably a Firefox bug since in Chrome there's no problem. But my client uses Firefox, so I need to solve this problem somehow. I'll report this bug to Mozilla, but I wouldn't like to wait years until they fix it.

Do you know any workaround that could be used here?

This is how the table is rendered in Firefox (it has much more rows in reality)

[image: rendered in browser]

But when I print it, some borders disappear from the second page.

[image: printed]

Here I zoomed into the second page:

[image: zoom]

Here's my example code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        th, td{
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">00</th><th colspan="2">01</th><th colspan="2">02</th><th colspan="2">03</th><th colspan="2">04</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>00</td><td>01</td><td>02</td><td>03</td><td>04</td><td>05</td><td>06</td><td>07</td><td>08</td><td>09</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>30</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td><td>35</td><td>36</td><td>37</td><td>38</td><td>39</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>40</td><td>41</td><td>42</td><td>43</td><td>44</td><td>45</td><td>46</td><td>47</td><td>48</td><td>49</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>50</td><td>51</td><td>52</td><td>53</td><td>54</td><td>55</td><td>56</td><td>57</td><td>58</td><td>59</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>60</td><td>61</td><td>62</td><td>63</td><td>64</td><td>65</td><td>66</td><td>67</td><td>68</td><td>69</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>70</td><td>71</td><td>72</td><td>73</td><td>74</td><td>75</td><td>76</td><td>77</td><td>78</td><td>79</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>80</td><td>81</td><td>82</td><td>83</td><td>84</td><td>85</td><td>86</td><td>87</td><td>88</td><td>89</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>90</td><td>91</td><td>92</td><td>93</td><td>94</td><td>95</td><td>96</td><td>97</td><td>98</td><td>99</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>00</td><td>01</td><td>02</td><td>03</td><td>04</td><td>05</td><td>06</td><td>07</td><td>08</td><td>09</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>30</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td><td>35</td><td>36</td><td>37</td><td>38</td><td>39</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>40</td><td>41</td><td>42</td><td>43</td><td>44</td><td>45</td><td>46</td><td>47</td><td>48</td><td>49</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>50</td><td>51</td><td>52</td><td>53</td><td>54</td><td>55</td><td>56</td><td>57</td><td>58</td><td>59</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>60</td><td>61</td><td>62</td><td>63</td><td>64</td><td>65</td><td>66</td><td>67</td><td>68</td><td>69</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>70</td><td>71</td><td>72</td><td>73</td><td>74</td><td>75</td><td>76</td><td>77</td><td>78</td><td>79</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>80</td><td>81</td><td>82</td><td>83</td><td>84</td><td>85</td><td>86</td><td>87</td><td>88</td><td>89</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>90</td><td>91</td><td>92</td><td>93</td><td>94</td><td>95</td><td>96</td><td>97</td><td>98</td><td>99</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>00</td><td>01</td><td>02</td><td>03</td><td>04</td><td>05</td><td>06</td><td>07</td><td>08</td><td>09</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>30</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td><td>35</td><td>36</td><td>37</td><td>38</td><td>39</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>40</td><td>41</td><td>42</td><td>43</td><td>44</td><td>45</td><td>46</td><td>47</td><td>48</td><td>49</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>50</td><td>51</td><td>52</td><td>53</td><td>54</td><td>55</td><td>56</td><td>57</td><td>58</td><td>59</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>60</td><td>61</td><td>62</td><td>63</td><td>64</td><td>65</td><td>66</td><td>67</td><td>68</td><td>69</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>70</td><td>71</td><td>72</td><td>73</td><td>74</td><td>75</td><td>76</td><td>77</td><td>78</td><td>79</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>80</td><td>81</td><td>82</td><td>83</td><td>84</td><td>85</td><td>86</td><td>87</td><td>88</td><td>89</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>90</td><td>91</td><td>92</td><td>93</td><td>94</td><td>95</td><td>96</td><td>97</td><td>98</td><td>99</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>00</td><td>01</td><td>02</td><td>03</td><td>04</td><td>05</td><td>06</td><td>07</td><td>08</td><td>09</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>30</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td><td>35</td><td>36</td><td>37</td><td>38</td><td>39</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>40</td><td>41</td><td>42</td><td>43</td><td>44</td><td>45</td><td>46</td><td>47</td><td>48</td><td>49</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>50</td><td>51</td><td>52</td><td>53</td><td>54</td><td>55</td><td>56</td><td>57</td><td>58</td><td>59</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>60</td><td>61</td><td>62</td><td>63</td><td>64</td><td>65</td><td>66</td><td>67</td><td>68</td><td>69</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>70</td><td>71</td><td>72</td><td>73</td><td>74</td><td>75</td><td>76</td><td>77</td><td>78</td><td>79</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>80</td><td>81</td><td>82</td><td>83</td><td>84</td><td>85</td><td>86</td><td>87</td><td>88</td><td>89</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>90</td><td>91</td><td>92</td><td>93</td><td>94</td><td>95</td><td>96</td><td>97</td><td>98</td><td>99</td>
    </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have done:

I wrapped the content of every second cell with a div.

Then I expanded the size of the div to the cell's size. Then I used the div's border-left property instead.

CSS (less):

```
tbody tr>td:nth-of-type(even){
    padding: 0 !important;
    &>div{
        padding: 2px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -1px;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-left-color: black;
    }
}
```